# Uploading files to a server that has Real Time Antivirus scan running

Tags: upload, antivirus

I need to allow users to upload files onto a server that has an antivirus program running with real-time scanning switched on.

What would be a good design to ensure that infected files are not uploaded to the server.

Questions -

1. would large files be copied onto disk and then immediately scanned, or would they be scanned as they are copied and not allowed to appear on disk if infected
2. Should i build a seperate infrastructure around this to specifically ionvoke a scan on the copied file ? this might be an issue if the file is deleted through the real-time scan

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are doing, but there ARE online virus scanning websites - just so that you know, and don't need to reinvent the wheel : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This depends on your antivirus system and OS. This should be easy to determine through testing. On Windows, it seems that most real time antivirus systems scan the file as it is written to disk, and well before the file can be executed, moved, or copied by Windows Explorer. Windows Explorer gets an error if it continues to try to access the file.
2. If the above doesn't meet your needs, then yes, you'll probably want to invoke the scan manually. If your antivirus automatically deletes or quarantines the file, you'd simply check to see if the file were still in its original location after the scan. Ideally, your antivirus would allow you to scan the file and return true or false as to whether it were infected, which would allow you to delete the file manually.

Comment: Thanks, I am interested in point 1 of your answer. Are there any more details around how Anti virus software do this operation ?

Comment: On Windows 32-bit OS, most anti-virus programs patched the kernel, which sits between the OS and the hardware, so they're able to intercept the files at a low level. On Windows 64-bit OS, Microsoft provides a security API, which basically provides the same access.